# How to give validation inside the gridview controls?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

```
 <tr>
 <asp:GridView ID="gvWH" runat="server" BorderColor="#BDBDBD" ShowFooter="True"
 CssClass="center" OnRowDataBound="gvWH_RowDataBound" 
 GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowDeleting="gvWH_RowDeleting"  
AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
       No Records found
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                     <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbirdtype" runat="server" 
                         AutoPostBack="true">
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVbirdtype" runat="server" 
                      ControlToValidate="ddlbirdtype"  
                  ValidationGroup="GridView1" InitialValue="0" Display="None"
                 ErrorMessage="Please select Bird Type"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="VCEbirdtype" runat="Server" 
              TargetControlID="RFVbirdtype" EnableViewState="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weight">
           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
               <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="BtnAdd_Click"
             ValidationGroup="GridView1" CausesValidation="true" />
                </FooterTemplate>
              <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
              </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td align="center">
   <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return validations1();" ValidationGroup="GridView1" CausesValidation="true"
     Style="height: 26px" />
     </td>
  </tr>
```

When i click on Outside "Save" button then it shows validations ..please help me

Comment: Give one try, remove OnClientClick="return validations1();" from outside button then validation control may fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **InitialValue="0"** attribute only makes you not getting validation, Please remove that. If Still you need that means then you have to specify First Item of dropdownList otherwise just remove it.

And Set **Display** as **Dynamic**
Try like this

```
<tr>
 <asp:GridView ID="gvWH" runat="server" BorderColor="#BDBDBD" ShowFooter="True"
 CssClass="center" OnRowDataBound="gvWH_RowDataBound" 
 GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowDeleting="gvWH_RowDeleting"  
AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
       No Records found
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                     <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbirdtype" runat="server" 
                         AutoPostBack="true">
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVbirdtype" runat="server" 
                      ControlToValidate="ddlbirdtype"  
                  ValidationGroup="GridView1" Display="Dynamic"
                 ErrorMessage="Please select Bird Type"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="VCEbirdtype" runat="Server" 
              TargetControlID="RFVbirdtype" EnableViewState="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weight">
           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
               <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="BtnAdd_Click"
             ValidationGroup="GridView1" CausesValidation="true" />
                </FooterTemplate>
              <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
              </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td align="center">
   <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ValidationGroup="GridView1" CausesValidation="true"
     Style="height: 26px" />
     </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Its working fine for me, and the problem is because of Diaplay and Initial Value only

Comment: K,where i delete intialvalue properity?

Comment: @SambaSiva Hi, I updated solution, now my  guess is about OnClientCLick in your Save Button, Remove that and check

Comment: Just Use my code, I did that, InitialValue in Requiredfieldvalidtor control

Comment: I have another  panel..it contain more controls also..so i added OnClientCLick validation ...

Comment: Just remove and Check now, If it's worked that is only problem so you need to Write the script vlearly

Comment: I agree your answer,Your code is obsoletely correct..but i can also add the OnClientCLick Validation..how can i add that...